# Dropdown does not hide properly in Microsoft edge after hover when floated

Tags: html, css, microsoft-edge, dropdown

I am learning how to make nav bars with drop downs. This works well on Firefox and Chrome, but not in Edge. The problem is that once the drop down has been displayed after the mouse was hovering over it, when the mouse is moved and it's time for it to have display: none, you can still see a tiny amount of the bottom sticking out where the dropdown was. This is only when the ul is floated.

I've removed a lot of css to leave what mainly is essential, but included the whole html, in case anyone wants to just copy and paste into a file to see. I'm am wondering if this is something I've done wrong, or a bug in Edge, and if anyone can tell me how I can prevent this from happening.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            .right {
                float: right;
            }

            .nav {
               background-color: #444;
            }

            .nav ul {
                list-style: none;
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
            }

            .nav li {
                font-size: 1.1em;
                display: inline-block;
            }

            .nav .dropdown {
                position: absolute;
                display: none;
                background-color: #444;
                font-size: 0.9em;
            }

            .nav .dropdown li {
                display: block;
            }

            .nav li:hover ul {
                display: block;
            }

            .nav a {
                text-decoration: none;
                color: #fff;
                display: block; 
            }

            .nav a {
                padding: 15px 25px 15px 25px;
            }
        </style>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="nav">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li class="right"><a href="#">Your...</a>
                    <ul class="dropdown">
                        <li><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Bookmarks</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Songs</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I may have been hasty posting this question. I have figured out a way of hiding the problem by adding a border to the nav bar.

```
 .nav {
      background-color: #444;
      border-bottom: solid #444 thin;
 }
```